# Erlang and Singleton good practice?

Tags: erlang, singleton

Since Erlang isnt really object oriented, there is no real singleton class but i guess
a process which is registered can be used as one.

Is it good practice to use registered processes for that inside an application to make the access easier?
Disadvantage i see that for example that you cannot run more than one instance of such an application inside one node.

Take as example a gui application with a process managing the events and some other responsible for the sound.
Would it be good practise to make those 2 "singleton" as registered processes and call them like `sound:play(file_name)` instead of storing the pid and doing `sound:play(Pid, file_name)`?

Comment: You can run many instances of a process running a module registered under different names. There is no inherent coupling between the name of the module which implements a process and the registered name of a process. It is just a common convention which works when you only want to run one instance.

Comment: I can think of a good use case for a singleton process and that would be for something like a user specific process that is always persistent, blocking and listening to a rabbitmq channel.  I prefer these messages to be processed in serial and I don't want multiple rabbitmq listeners, just the one per user.  My question is if I have distributed nodes, should these singleton processes be spread out evenly amongst nodes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is fairly common to use a gen_server under a registered name to do exactly this. You can export functions from that same module which simply do a gen_server:call against the named process in question.

(Arguably, Erlang is more "really" OO than what you're probably used to. But that's not what this question is about.)

Comment: Also, if you want to play more than one sound at a time, its dead simple to launch a process that will play the sound and terminate. If you're not using OTP (you should look into it), then you can roll that by hand easily enough. This may break down a bit if you end up playing too many sounds at the same time from a UX perspective though.